# Why is my environment object throwing an error when I try to access its variables?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a nested set of environments I made by converting lists using `as.environment`. Accessing their elements used to work. I have updated my version of R since and I suspect it may have something to do with it.

The result, from the console (RStudio):

```
> class(orthogroupEnv)
[1] "environment"
> class(orthogroupEnv$OG0010000)
[1] "environment"
> names(orthogroupEnv$OG0010000)[1]
[1] "OG0009000"
Error in order(typeScores, scores) : argument lengths differ
In addition: Warning message:
In completions$type == .rs.acCompletionTypes$DATAFRAME & !completions$context %in%  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> orthogroupEnv$OG0010000$
```

The error pops up when I type the last '$', above that line.

What is going on, and can I fix this so I don't have to recreate the environments? It is computationally expensive to do so.

Comment: Do you observe this behaviour when your run R from the command line rather than from RStudio?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I found it to work as expected from the command line. I am developing a Shiny app and RStudio is invaluable for this. Any idea how I can get it to work correctly in RStudio?

Comment: It's a bug in RStudio - have you tried installing the latest version? Perhaps even the latest daily build?

Comment: Perfect - 2023.03.1+446 does not work but 2023.05.0-daily-366 does (MacOS, ARM).